# Using gitmessage template in VS 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio

Currently working on a project and wanted to set some template git messages when anybody checks something in that it helps remind what should be in the commit message. I have been able to do this in normal git using gitmessage, but cannot seem to get it to appear in Visual Studio 2019 when committing to git that way. Any ideas or sources that could help me out?
[Git Message VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SODJF.png)